# Sendmail adds X-Authentication-Warning for trusted users?

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail

So, I've digged through tons of articles and answers to configure sendmail on Ubuntu 12.04 correctly but still my emails are being flagged with `X-Authentication-Warning` header by sendmail:

> X-Authentication-Warning: advisor.travel: www-data set sender to
>   noreply@advisor.travel using -f

by simple console call:

> echo "Test email being by sendmail" | sudo -u www-data
>   /usr/sbin/sendmail -f noreply@advisor.travel

Please mind that I am not trying to configure a spam-proof setup here as everything regarding SPF, DKIM and other stuff are already in place :)

Sendmail info:

```
# sendmail -d0.1
Version 8.14.4
 Compiled with: DNSMAP LDAPMAP LDAP_REFERRALS LOG MAP_REGEX MATCHGECOS
        MILTER MIME7TO8 MIME8TO7 NAMED_BIND NETINET NETINET6 NETUNIX
        NEWDB NIS NISPLUS PIPELINING SASLv2 SCANF SOCKETMAP STARTTLS
        TCPWRAPPERS USERDB USE_LDAP_INIT XDEBUG

============ SYSTEM IDENTITY (after readcf) ============
      (short domain name) $w = advisor
  (canonical domain name) $j = advisor.travel
         (subdomain name) $m = travel
              (node name) $k = advisor.travel
========================================================
```

Configuration:

```
/etc/mail  # cat trusted-users 
www-data

/etc/mail  # cat sendmail.mc | grep use_ct_file
FEATURE(`use_ct_file')dnl

/etc/mail  # cat sendmail.cf | grep -A 5 trusted
Ft/etc/mail/trusted-users %[^\#]
Troot
Tdaemon
Tuucp
```

No luck, still having `X-Authentication-Warning` header :/

I've read in several sources that trusted users file should be enabled in submit.mc but no idea how :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `FEATURE(use_ct_file)` to `submit.mc` and generate new `submit.cf`.

---

**Explanation:**
Sendmail-8.12+ uses submit.cf to control "send an email" sendmail execution.
It has been introduced to avoid installing sendmail as set root uid (security risk).

[Sendmail: Secure Install](http://web.archive.org/web/20160705154801/http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/security/secure-install/)

Comment: It worked! But where can I find the details about WHY should I do it? :/

Comment: Sendmail command you executed to send email is controlled by submit.cf [in sendmail-8.12+] see https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/security/secure-install/  . It seems that sendmail documentation has not been properly and throughly "synchronized" with many consequences of the above change.